# I am struggling with a SQL query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

From one table (i.e. `tblCases`), I can count and group each protocol based on its ID for a given date interval:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CountAndGroupByProtocol]
   (@startDate datetime, @endDate datetime) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        COUNT(C.protocolID) AS total, protocolID  
    FROM 
        tblCases C 
    WHERE 
        C.dateOpened BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate
    GROUP BY 
        C.protocolID
    ORDER BY 
        total DESC
END


EXEC [dbo].[sp_CountAndGroupByProtocol] '2015-01-01', '2016-08-01'
```

And I get the correct result:

```
     total    protocolID
1       60          3860
2       43          5829
...
```

Each protocol is linked to one scientist (i.e `namePI`). `tblProtocols`:

```
ID   protocol_ID namePI
------------------------
 1          3860      1
 2          5829      5
..
```

`tblPI`:

```
ID  firstName  lastName
------------------------
 1       John     Smith
 2      Davis      Emma
...
```

I would like to add the person's last name and first name for each protocol:

```
      total    protocolID    lastName    firstName
---------------------------------------------------
1       60           3860       Smith         John
2       43           5829       Davis         Emma
...
```

I know that join should work, but wherever I put "JOIN", I get

> error: incorrect syntax near JOIN

Is it because I am using SQL Server?

I would greatly appreciate the community's feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Show what query you are having trouble with and what error you are receiving.  This sounds like a basic `join` though...

Comment: Side note:  _especially_ on SQL Server [don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Just don't.  Date/time/timestamp are all positive, contiguous-range types, and as such should always be queried as lower-bound inclusive (`>=`), upper-bound exclusive (`<`).  (Although note that sometimes the actual statement may appear to flip this because of the actual bound)

Comment: Where you have `FROM tblCases C` you want to put `FROM tblCases C JOIN tblPI P ON P.ID = C.ID` or something like that. Likely you're putting the join in the wrong place or forgetting to tell SQL what columns to join on.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. It's clear you're having difficulty, or you wouldn't be posting here, and the tag you added tells us it's with SQL Server. Removing both of those from the title leaves zero information. Your title should explain the specific problem you're having or question you're asking, and it should be clear enough to be useful to future readers who see it in a list of search results here. Imagine trying to figure out how to solve a problem, doing a search, and seeing dozens of posts saying *I have a problem/issue/can't do this* - would they help?

Comment: @Clockwork,  Your point about Between is, as is often the case, not always true.  It is true only for DateTime attributes, and then only if the data stored in the attribute includes time values as well as date values.  It not true at all for date attributes or for datetime attributes which only contain date values.

Comment: @CharlesBretana - `Date`s use an exclusive upper bound for, at minimum, the same reasons iterating through an array does.  The more usual reason, though, is it ensures consistency with all other types, and ensures that when the underlying type changes you don't have to go scrambling around finding everything that touches it.  Oh, and if you can manage to keep your `DateTime`s completely free from anomalies, I'll be impressed.  The underlying philosophy is that there is no "last instant", only a first instant when something is different.

Comment: Sorry, when using `Between` on Dates, the upper bound is inclusive, just as the lower bound is.  And, in SQL Server, it is trivial to ensure that datetime attributes representing dates contain only dates, as there is a data type expressly for that purpose. But even if you're forced to deal with versions prior to when Date datatype was introduced, all you need to do is design so that all inserts/updates channel through a single entry point (Stored proc is best) where any potential client data values are stripped to date only before they reach the database table.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you want, but if you post your code that is erroring out we can likely give you a precise reason for it.

```
SELECT     COUNT(C.protocolID) AS total, c.protocolID, lastName, firstName 
FROM       tblCases C 
INNER JOIN tblProtocols P on P.Protocol_ID = C.ProtocolID
INNER JOIN tblPI PI on PI.ID = P.NamePI
WHERE      C.dateOpened BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate
GROUP BY   C.protocolID, lastName, firstName
ORDER BY   total desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was getting an error until I finished writing the code and everything worked!